# Elasticsearch get index creation script

Tags: elasticsearch, import, snapshot

I got one index for model that has different mappings

```
{
  "user_index": {
    "aliases": {
      "entities": {}
    },
    "mappings": {
      "user": {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "_timestamp": {},
        "properties": {
          "firstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"        
          } ....
```

and I want to change id type to `long`

How can I get and copy this index creation script and just change 1 type for the field with the minimal work like get import script for mysql in workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can push your new index mapping with the desired change then use the reindex api to copy data from your old index.

Comment: that's great ! You should validate the answer for future reference.